# PHP5.4 mongodb unauthorized when execute, but find works

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm facing issue where i could authenticate into the database and do any query or reducemap via console,
but when i ran the execute syntax on php side, it return error :unathorized.

mongodb->collectionname->find() works...
Example failed code:

```
  mongodb->execute('
  db.campaign_period.find({"_id.period":{"$gte": ISODate("2011-01-01T00:00:00"), "$lte": ISODate("2011-12-31T23:59:59")}, "$and": [{"$or": [{"value.section": "APPAREL & ACCESSORIES"}]}]}).sort({"value.country":1,"value.state":1,"value.section":1,"value.advertiser":1,"_id.siteref":1,"_id.panelno":1,"_id.period":1}).forEach(function(data){ db.campaign_report_mradminraw.insert(data); });
  ');
```

Comment: You need to supply a bit more information, especially how you set-up your connection and how you authenticate. I also don't understand why you run your find like that, as $mongodb->campain_period->find() works just as well...

Comment: its most likely a mongodb bug since 2.4
when ive noauth = false, auth = true, 50% of the time the cursor return unauthorized. hope they will fix this soon

Comment: Not sure why you jump to conclusions, but you did not provide any information that was asked for...